# Delete and fill the information

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Hello I have this table and I want to be able to delete the data on P(number) and tituloP(number).
I have done the query to delete if the user choose the last P(number) its the easier.
Now I have to do a cicle that if user delete a middle data it auto fill 1 field.

There is the example:

```
IIDD | ID | Num_Slides | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | tituloP1 | tituloP2 | tituloP3 | tituloP4 | tituloP5 
1    | 4  | 5          | 1  | 2  | 4  | 5  | 2  |Sometext  |Sometext2 |Sometext3 |Sometext4 |Sometext5 |
```

If user choose to delete P5 its easier I just need to fill the P5 with 0 and tituloP5 with blank field and Num_Slides 4

But If user choose to delete P3, tituloP3 I have to set P5 to 0 and tituloP5 to blank field SET P4 to 2 tituloP4 to Sometext5 and SET P3 to 5 tituloP3 to Sometext4 this way the information will be updated without P'gaps

I have this for cicle so far but dont work

```
if (isset($_POST['Confirmar'])){
    $max = 5;
    $menos1 = $max - 1;
    for ($i = 4; $i >= 1; $i--){
        $sqlya="SELECT P$i, tituloP$i FROM slider_settings where slider_settings.ID = 4";
        for ($k = $menos1; $k <= $menos1; $k++){
            $inserirya = "UPDATE slider_settings SET P$k ='P$i', tituloP$k ='tituloP$i' where slider_settings.ID = 4";
            $con1 = $connect->query($sqlya);
            $com2 = $connect->query($inserirya);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: you realize that you're trying to update your entire database

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updated sorry

Comment: where's the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited

Comment: any errors via php's error reporting and on the query?

Comment: Nop, I think the problem is on for $i  since he doesnt move on PuTTY I can see that $i is always P4

Answer (score -1):

//This Will Provide U Update Query

```
function createUpdateString($position,&$str){

if($position==5){
    return false;
}
$nextPosition =  $position+1;

$str[] = " P{$position} =  P{$nextPosition}";
$str[] = " tituloP{$position} =  tituloP{$nextPosition}";
return createUpdateString($nextPosition,$str);
}
```

//Supose Your removing 3

//Update The p3 and tituloP3 values 0 and ""

```
$updatePostion = 3;
$str = array();
//This function will create query string for you
createUpdateString($updatePostion,$str);
$queryString = implode(",",$str);

if(!empty($queryString)){
$query = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET ".$queryString ."where slider_settings.ID = 4";
}
```

Comment: ~The problem is if I delete page 3 without fill it with page 4 info the site will display a empty page